# Filter sensitive parameters from logs in clojure ring app

Tags: clojure, ring

I'm using `wrap-with-logger` (from [ring.middleware.logger](https://github.com/pjlegato/ring.middleware.logger)) and `wrap-params` (from [ring.middleware.params](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.params.html)) middlewares in my application. Any simple way to filter sensitive parameters (password, credit card number etc.) from logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also consider migrating to [ring-logger](https://github.com/nberger/ring-logger) which includes a [feature to redact sensitive information](https://github.com/nberger/ring-logger#password-redacted):

> By default, ring-logger will redact an authorization header or any param named `password` (at any nesting level). If you want ring-logger to redact other params you can configure the `redact-keys` option:
>
> ```
>    (wrap-with-logger app {:redact-keys #{:senha :token})
> ```
>
> Ring-logger will walk through the params and headers and redact any key whose name is found in that `redact-keys` set.

There's also [ring-logger-onelog](https://github.com/nberger/ring-logger-onelog) that should make it very easy to migrate from [ring.middleware.logger](https://github.com/pjlegato/ring.middleware.logger) to ring-logger

Comment: How do you get that useful request-id thing (that %x logs) with ring-logger?

Comment: @BobKuhar it's only supported by ring-logger-onelog currently. There's an open issue for adding it to ring-logger (or ring-logger-timbre at the very least): https://github.com/nberger/ring-logger/issues/7. Feel free to chime in there. PRs are welcome too :)

Answer (score 2):

You may implement custom `pre-logger` that filters request according to your needs.

See the following:

```
(use 'ring.adapter.jetty)
(require '[ring.middleware.logger :as logger])

(defn handler [request]
  {:status 200
   :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
   :body "Hello World"})

(run-jetty
 (logger/wrap-with-logger
  handler
  :pre-logger
  (fn [options req]
    ;; Filtering goes here
    (let [filtered-req (filter-sensitive-data req)]
      ((:info options) "Filtered requrest is: " filtered-req))))
 {:port 8080})
```

Note, while documentation [claims](https://github.com/pjlegato/ring.middleware.logger/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/logger.clj#L127-L128) that `pre-logger` accepts only one argument, [truly it is two-arg function](https://github.com/pjlegato/ring.middleware.logger/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/logger.clj#L145-L146).